# Fubini and the order of integration

Tags: integration

I want to show that the order of integration is irrelevant as consequence of Fubini's theorem.Thus to say that for
every given permutation the value of  $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\dots \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x_1,\dots, x_n) d\mu_1({\sigma(1)}) \dots d\mu_1(\sigma(n))$ remains the same (where
$\sigma$ is a permutation of n elements and $\mu_1$ the one-deimensional Lebesgue-measure).

I suppose that since every permutation is writable as a product of transpositions, it is enough to show that for every transposition the value of the integral remains the same.
What might be reduced to the fact that we show for two indices in direct neighborhood (i and i+1), that the former is the case.
Do you think this is consistent? Or is there an easier way?

Greetings

Rico

Comment: We will have questions of measurability.  What sort of measurability do you assume for $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, and does that imply that you have measurability as a function of two variables after you fix some variables, integrate other variables, leaving only two variables free?

Comment: I assume it to be measurable about the Lebesgue-measure. Thus I would have said that with a link to Tonelli the inner integrals which compose $F(x_i,x_j)$ are measurable relating to the fact that the measurbaility might be deduced for $F^\pm$ and thus for F itself. But now I'm not sure whether this is correct. Do you have a tip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply Fubini's Theorem repeatedly to bring $d\mu_1(x_1)$ to the inner most integral; then apply Fubini's Theorem repeatedly to bring $d\mu_1(x_2)$ to the next integral, etc.

Comment: Ok, the use of Fubini you suppose uses that we might change neighbouring $x_i \wedge x_j$, am I right? Resulting in the identity $F(x_i,x_j)= \underbrace{\int_{\mathbb{R}} \dots \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x_1,..., x_n) dx_1...dx_{i-1}}_{i-1}$. Let thus be $G(x_i,x_j)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} F(x_i,x_j) dx_idx_j$ than this equals to $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} F(x_i,x_j) dx_jdx_i$. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes. All you need is to keep on interchanging neighboring integrals until you get what you want.