# Measurability under certain operations

Tags: integration

Suppose we have a function $f(x_1,...x_n)$ that is measurable and integrable under the Lebesgue measure. Now we want to look at the functions $F(x_i,x_j)= \int_{\mathbb{R}}\dots \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x_1,\dots , x_n) d\mu_1 \dots d\mu_{i-1}$ and $G(x_i,x_j)= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} F(x_i,x_j) d\mu_i  d\mu_j$. Where i and j are in direct neighborhood, thus to say that j equals i+1 and $\mu $ is the Lebesgue measure.
Now my question is one that arose in the context of another question ([Fubini and the order of integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2818016/fubini-and-the-order-of-integration)). So I may cite what one of the participants said:

"What sort of measurability do you assume for $f(x_1,…,x_n)$, and does that imply that you have measurability as a function of two variables after you fix some variables, integrate other variables, leaving only two variables free?"

In first place I would've said that by the use of Tonelli's theorem the result is clear.

But now I'm not as sure as I was before, because by the use of Tonelli I only get statements about the inner integrals and not for the searched operations.

So how can I show, what the citation asks?

Greetings Rico

Comment: Fubini /Tonelli does give you measurability of $F$ and $G$.

Comment: Does it even give me these points, if I have only Fubini and Tonelli for Lebesgue-Borel-measurable functions?
Is what the commentator in the other thread asked, all a case of the measurability of the inner integral?